# How to get Ubuntu Touch on Samsung Galaxy S3?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, samsung

I guess I have a two part question. I've looked over the guide on how to set up a build environment and even tried doing some of those steps, every route failure.

Why can't I just use someone else's recovery image or .zip and boot from there on a rooted phone?

Does anyone have a working .zip for Samsung Galaxy s3 i9300?

EDIT: mine is the sprint one. Seems to be Qualcomm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galaxy S3 is not officially supported by Ubuntu touch but, there is a ROM available you can flash via clockworkmod.

[i9300 Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/i9300)

[i9300 Ubuntu XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/orig-development/discontinued-ubuntu-touch-13-10-builds-t2315397)

[Rom download link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/orig-development/discontinued-ubuntu-touch-13-10-builds-t2315397)

However, this ROM is discontinued since 2013, and according to the XDA page: "No GSM/Phone calls". So, try at your own risk.

Comment: yea, I followed some of those. Hard bricked my phone. Now to try my tablet!